# Laravel how to manage many to many relationship for FAQs

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am working on adding FAQs in database using laravel 5.6 many to many relationship. Here are my migrations:

**Faq Category: (List of all the types of FAQs)**

```
Schema::create('faq_categories', function (Blueprint $table) {
                $table->increments('id');
                $table->string('name');
                $table->softDeletes();
                $table->timestamps();
            });
```

**Faq Table:**

```
 Schema::create('faqs', function (Blueprint $table) {
                $table->increments('id');
                $table->string('title', 160);
                $table->longText('description');
                $table->boolean('published')->default(0);
                $table->softDeletes();
                $table->timestamps();
            });
```

**Faq Types: (All the FAQs categories for particular FAQ)**

```
Schema::create('faq_types', function (Blueprint $table) {
               $table->increments('id');
                $table->integer('faq_id')->unsigned();
                $table->foreign('faq_id')->references('id')->on('faqs')->onDelete('cascade');
                $table->integer('faq_category_id')->unsigned();
                $table->foreign('faq_category_id')->references('id')->on('faq_categories')->onDelete('cascade');
                $table->timestamps();
            });
```

I have defined relationship like this:

**App\FaqCategory**

```
class FaqCategory extends Model {

    use SoftDeletes;

    public function faqs() {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Faq');
    }
}
```

**App\Faq**

```
class Faq extends Model {

    use SoftDeletes;

    public function categories() {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\FaqCategory');
    }

}
```

I want all the FAQs by their category. Suppose there `General`, `Other` category in `faq_categories` table then I want faqs grouped by `General`, `Other`.

But I am not able to retrieve all faqs grouped by category. I did following but facing error:

```
$faq = FaqCategory::find(1);
        return $faq->faqs;
        dd($faq);
```

**Error:**

SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'db_name.faq_faq_category' doesn't exist.

Can anyone suggest me how to deal with this situation or best way to handle this?

Comment: where you have declared the table name in model like 
protected $table = tbl_ads';

Comment: No, I have not defined it in model

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to define your relationships as

```
public function faqs() {
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Faq', 'faq_types');
}
```

and

```
public function categories() {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\FaqCategory', 'faq_types');
    }
```

since you're not following convention.

Laravel by default looks for table 'faq_faq_category' (singular model names in alphabetical order).

You can read more about defining Many to many relationships [in the documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many)

Comment: Suppose If I modify my table faq_type to faq_faq_category then will this solve my problem?

Comment: Yes, you can either modify table name to match convention or tell Laravel to use your table 'faq_types' in relationship definitions as i showed above

Comment: But how can I store data for relationship then, I have modified table name to `faq_faq_category` instead `faq_types`

Comment: To store data you can use attach method, i.e `$faq = Faq::find(1);
        $faq->categories()->attach([1,2]);`

The code above above connects faq with id=1 with categories 1 and 2, so it creates 2 rows in faq_types table. Attach method accepts single as well as array of ids

Comment: How to i get faqs grouped by category

Comment: You can do `FaqCategory::with('faqs')->get()` to get all categories with related faqs